# Question title text changes to "undefined more votes needed" when I close a question as 'unclear what you're asking' in the moderator queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, moderator-queue

I [voted to close this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316681/how-to-use-handler-to-display-images-from-database-without-passing-id-in-queryst#question) as `unclear what you're asking` after receiving flags on it in the moderator queue.

Once I did that, the text for the question title in the moderator queue changed from:

> How to use handler to display images from database without passing ID in querystring?

to

> How to use handler to display images from database without passing ID in querystring? [undefined more votes needed]

The text on the main page has stayed consistent with the new 'on hold' verbiage, however.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: undefined more votes needed image]

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186096/this-question-needs-undefined-more-close-votes

Comment: Verified - just saw this come up while casting the fifth vote on a question in 10K tools.

Comment: The title text is _completely_ descriptive. The question needs more upvotes but that operation would be undefined because the question is bad enough to warrant closing.

Comment: Happens to custom off topic too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186021/question-title-text-changes-to-undefined-more-votes-needed-when-i-close-a-ques\

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in 2013.7.22.1257 (meta) and 2013.7.22.881 (sites).