# This question needs undefined more close votes

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, 10k-tools, flag-queue

I saw a question in the 10k review queue that had 4 close votes. When I voted to close it, I got this:

[image]

This always happens after I vote to close in the 10k queue (it just happened again when there were only 3 close votes. and again with 2. see image below).

[image]

I'm using Chrome 28.0.1500.52 (Official Build 207119) m on Windows 7.

Comment: Counting to 5 is hard...